# multiple try/except in a single function does not work

Tags: python

```
 def creating_folder_for_csv_files(cwd):
     try:
         os.makedirs(cwd+'\\migration_data\\trade')
     except os.error, e:
         print "Could not create the destination folder for CSV files"
    # end of first try/except block

     try:
         os.makedirs(cwd+'\\migration_data\\voucher')
     except os.error, e:
         print "Could not create the destination folder for CSV files"
```

In my code, the first try/except block works but the second does not. What's the problem?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean with 'does not [work]?' What is the expected behavior, and what is the behavior you are seeing instead?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? It doesn't create the directory? It throws an exception? Neither?

Comment: As a side note it worth to use [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join one or more path components.

Answer (score 0):

The `voucher` might already exist.